# Simulate phonecall with Android

Tags: android

Is it possible to dial a certain phone number in Android which my app can intercept and cancel the actual dialing? Instead of having a number dialed I would like a message (TTS) to be played.

My phone is always connected to my build in car kit but it only supports dialing numbers. So I would like to "dial" a number from the car kit and hear the traffic information, without having to call an actual number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want, there is [an Android Developers blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/01/processing-ordered-broadcasts.html) regarding some details on intercepting outgoing calls and cancelling them (by handling the [ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL) broadcast).